# Reset nproc value of root user

Tags: apache-2.2, rhel6

Website goes down and apache error log is below:

[Sat Dec 09 19:23:22 2017] [alert] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: setuid: unable to change to uid: 2
[Sat Dec 09 19:23:22 2017] [alert] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: setuid: unable to change to uid: 2
[Sat Dec 09 19:23:22 2017] [alert] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: setuid: unable to change to uid: 2
[Sat Dec 09 19:23:26 2017] [alert] Child 3148 returned a Fatal error... Apache is exiting!
[Sat Dec 09 19:23:26 2017] [emerg] (22)Invalid argument: couldn't grab the accept mutex
[Sat Dec 09 19:23:26 2017] [emerg] (22)Invalid argument: couldn't grab the accept mutex

This error may be because of nproc value. When I run ulimit -u as root get the value 150 . So I tried to increase npoc value but its not changing .

Steps taken:

Using RHEL6 . When I run ulimit -u as root or other user get the value 150 . 
I checked the file /etc/security/limits.conf which has entry
*  hard   nproc 150 which I commented (#).

File /etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf 
has default value

*soft nproc 10240

root       soft    nproc     unlimited

restarted httpd service still ulimit -u returns 150 .

How to set the default nproc value ?